# Objective C - Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'int*'

Tags: objective-c, ios

In AppDelegate.m Why I got this message error

> Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'int*' from 'MyPlugin*'

on this line:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

self.myPlugin = [[MyPlugin alloc] init];
```

In AppDelegate.h I have:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyPlugin *myPlugin;
```

In MyPlugin I have:

```
#import "MyPlugin.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@implementation MyPlugin

- (void)dealloc {

    [super dealloc];

}

- (MyPlugin*)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {

    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Have you included MyPlugin.h in AppDelegate.m?

Comment: Have you either synthesized your property (@synthesize myPlugin;) or implemented the setter/getter methods?

Comment: @cli_hlt oops I'm stupid newbie I did it in AppDelegate.m thanks this drove me crazy :)